# Json-Android Getting error while calling values

Tags: android-json

My Json Array of object is looks as

```
 [{"Temp_Password":"arun111","Password":""}]
```

In my Android code I have been used AsyncTask task to execute HTTP request,
In preexecute method() by using toast I can get this as string`[{"Temp_Password":"arun111","Password":""}]`

I have tried to to get individual values inside this Json ,but i cannot get expected result

My Java code

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //View your result here.
           JSONArray arr = null;
           String a = null;
           String b = null;
           try {
            arr=new JSONArray(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           JSONObject obj=new JSONObject((Map) arr);
            try {
            a = obj.getString("Temp_Password");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            b = obj.getString("Password");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           Toast.makeText(Certify_Login.this,a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Toast.makeText(Certify_Login.this,b, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```

Error

```
   03-08 00:50:33.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1788): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

Comment: JSONObject obj=new JSONObject((Map) arr);  On this line why are using the map class, am no table to understand this? The exception is because you are trying to typecast your array into a MAP which is not possible!

Comment: code suggestions,map this to JsonObject.

Comment: JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(arr); remove Map and try!

Comment: I solved it now, The problem is due to one factor ,,that is
I have to get jsonobject from jsonArray,,,,

Comment: If your problem is solved, select an answer and mark it as closed! :)

Comment: What technical error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(arr);
```

remove Map and try because the JSONObject expects a JSONArray and the problem was that it was being typcasted to Map Object